# Close-up ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to produce a close-up of a grid of gaze path visualizations in `ggplot2`. Say I have the three distributions of X/Y values shown in the three panels in the upper row, where the gaze paths in the panel to the left and in the middle have such a small radius they can barely be seen.
[image]

How can I home in on a closer X/Y range so the gaze paths can be distinguished more clearly?

I've been using this code so far. The problem with it is that I suspect that it **eliminates values** so they fit the plotting range. This is most probably the case in the panel on the right in the lower row: there should be gaze paths that extend to the very margins of the plot but there are none!

A. For the panels in the **upper row**:

```
# Get the combined X and Y axis limits, with pretty breaks:

xbreaks <- pretty(c(layer_data(f_A)$x, layer_data(f_B)$x, layer_data(f_C)$x))
ybreaks <- pretty(c(layer_data(f_A)$y, layer_data(f_B)$y, layer_data(f_C)$y))


# Assign the limits to the plots:

plot1 <- f_A + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks, limits = range(xbreaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = ybreaks, limits = range(ybreaks))

plot2 <- f_B + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks, limits = range(xbreaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = ybreaks, limits = range(ybreaks))

plot3 <- f_C + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks, limits = range(xbreaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = ybreaks, limits = range(ybreaks))


# Plot together:

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)
```

B. For the panels in the **lower row**:

```
# Reduce the X/Y range:
xbreaks <- xbreaks/12
ybreaks <- ybreaks/12

# as above ...
```

How can produce a close-up of the three distributions that represents all shown values as they are?

Comment: Can you provide some data to reproduce this?

Comment: Set the limits via `coord_cartesian` to zoom in on the data range. Setting the limits via the scale will remove all obs which does not fall into the limits.

Comment: As stefan said, use https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html

Comment: An alternative could be to use `facet_wrap()`.  This would produce the three panels, and the axes of each panel can be set independently, with the scales parameter.